# android: How to access UI objects from a user defined class

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a main activity with a button, in the on-click method, I am instatiating a DownloadManager class which creates a thread pool to download videos from a given URL using multiple threads.

the issue is, how do I post status of each thread to the UI editText object?

I am using Handler in my DownloadManager class which instantiates the threads to run parallely.

Following is the MainActivity button on click code:

```
public void buttonClick(View view) {
    EditText eText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText); //URL input text box
    EditText eText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2); //output text box
    new DownloadManager(eText1.getText().toString(), this.getFilesDir()).runDownloadThreadPool();
```

Following is the DownloadManager Constructor:

```
public DownloadManager(String url, File f) {
    this.url1 = url;
    this.f = f;
    sDM = this;
    mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message inputMessage){
            DownloaderThreadPool t = (DownloaderThreadPool) inputMessage.obj;
            //Toast.makeText(android.os.Environment.getApplicationContext(), t.threadMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    };
}
```

How do I pass the eText object in the first code to the DownloadManager so it can be updated in the handleMessage override function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it in via the constructor:

```
public DownloadManager(String url, File f, EditText editText) {
        this.url1 = url;
        this.f = f;
        sDM = this;
        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message inputMessage){
                DownloaderThreadPool t = (DownloaderThreadPool) inputMessage.obj;
                //Toast.makeText(android.os.Environment.getApplicationContext(), t.threadMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                editText.setText("Some text");
            }
        };
    }
```

And then pass it in when you instantiate your DownloadManager class:

```
new DownloadManager(eText1.getText().toString(), this.getFilesDir(), eText).runDownloadThreadPool();
```

Comment: @Muhammad, Okay edited answer, seems like I was wrong about that. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Just add it as another parameter to the constructor.

```
public DownloadManager(EditText outputUI, String url, File f) {
  this.outputUI = outputUI;
  ...
  mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message inputMessage){
            DownloaderThreadPool t = (DownloaderThreadPool) inputMessage.obj;
            outputUI.setText(t.threadMessage);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 : pass a instance of EditText to DownloadManager by constructor，as above;
2 : by callback. As follows:

at first , define a callback:

```
public interface OnStatusChangedListener {

    public void onStatusChanged(int status);

}
```

and then implements OnStatusChangedListener interface:

```
OnStatusChangedListener mListener = new OnStatusChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(int status) {
        //editText.setText(String.valueOf(status));
    }
};

public DownloadManager(String url, File f, final OnStatusChangedListener   listener) {
    this.url1 = url;
    this.f = f;
    sDM = this;
    mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message inputMessage){
            DownloaderThreadPool t = (DownloaderThreadPool) inputMessage.obj;
            //listener.onStatusChanged(status);
        }
    };
}
```

last,pass mListener in when you instantiate your DownloadManager class:

```
new DownloadManager(eText1.getText().toString(), this.getFilesDir(), mListener).runDownloadThreadPool();
```